# Discarding view after use with swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift

When my app starts, a login button is displayed. This is the LoginViewController. I instantiate a UINavigationViewController having the LoginViewController as rootViewController. Then, after logging in (using Facebook SDK) I display a second view, a TableViewController. Like so:

```
    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(false);
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(
        tableView, animated: false
    );
```

There are a few problems with this approach, though. For starters, the second view displays the back button, which I know I can hide (and should, because I popped the first view). But, worst, the navigationController does not get assigned to the TableViewController, which currently only displays a logout button. So, when I press logout, the following obviously crashes:

```
    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(false);
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(
        loginView, animated: false
    );
```

The thing is: if I close the app with an active login (that is, a facebook login token is cached), I want it to go directly to the second view controller (table view). I have this in may AppDelegate, at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    if (Session.activeSession().isOpen()) {
        rootViewController = tableView;
    }
    else {
        rootViewController = loginView;
    }
```

What's the best approach for this scenario? Maybe I should just stack the two views (by not popping)? If so, how do I get the second view to be under the same navigationController? Trying to unwrap tableView throws an exception when the app starts without a login token, after performing a login, and then logout.

Best.

Comment: How about `navigationController.viewControllers = [tableView]`?

Comment: I think that does not set tableView.navigationController, or does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great opportunity for a modal view controller! Use a `UINavigationController` for whatever you need it for (table view plus other details views off that). But when you need the user to login, use `presentViewController` from the navigation controller to show another controller in front. This can be a `UINavigationController` itself, or a simple `UIViewController`. When you're done with it, call the dismiss method and it will slide off, leaving your base navigation controller there, ready for use. Hope that helps!

Comment: Seems great =) I hadn't thought of model views! Thanks